# How do I connect a Windows Phone device with an Arduino?

Tags: windows-phone-7, arduino, sensors

I want to capture distances from sensors, using an Arduino and a [Windows Phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7) device. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone 7 SDK does not give access to the USB port or Bluetooth on the phone, so you can't use that. So I think the best way (and probably only way on Windows Phone 7) would be to communcate over Internet or local network with the Arduino acting as a server which the Windows Phone 7 app connects too.

Here are some examples of an Arduino [web server](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) and [TCP server](http://www.lauridmeyer.com/2012/04/simple-arduino-tcp-server-using-the-ethernetshield-and-a-java-client/).

For the Windows Phone client I would check out either [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: This will work, i wrote a RC car control app for my WinPhone7 a while back... BUT TCP isnt as real time as you would want it, so go about and build a remote controlled tanks or something. I modded a RC race car

Comment: Hello, Do I could to use a ethernet shield with an arduino or xbee board? thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Phone 8 SDK:

Consider establishing an App to Device communication through [Bluetooth API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which became available for developers in the release. [Bluetooth App to Device application sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-device-644870ba), available on MSDN, is the way to go.

There is another option in Windows Phone 8, using [Proximity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (a set of classes which works with NFC), which is more applicable for a short range communication.

As for Arduino, there is certainly a Bluetooth module.

### Windows Phone 7 SDK:

No way to establish a peer-to-peer communication with a third party device. A workaround would be to connect them through a network, as was proposed by Johan.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually made a Windows Phone 8 App that connects to an Arduino using the Sparkfun Bluetooth Silver Modem. Issues is, even after I get them connected, I can't get either the Arduino to receive the input OR I can't get the WP8 App to successfully send to the Arduino...

My GitHub for the project is: https://github.com/lanceseidman/Arduino-Bluetooth-WinPhone8

Hoping everyone can try and help on the project.

My Breadboard photos will be up soon and my Arduino Code.